# Unable to find zipalign in Android sdk/tools

Tags: android

I have been zipalign-ing for almost a year now for each release. But it seems as though the latest Android SDK does not come with zipalign anymore. Has the process changed? Am I still supposed to be zipalign-ing but with some other tool?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`zipalign` has moved to be part of the "build tools", and can be found in the various `build-tools/` directories in your Android SDK installation. For example, on my Ubuntu machine, I have `zipalign` in `build-tools/19.1.0/` and `build-tools/20.0.0/` in my SDK installation, as I have the both the 19.1 and 20 "Android SDK Build-tools" installed in the SDK Manager.

As ben75 notes, Gradle for Android should pull in the `zipalign` associated with the build tools you request in your `build.gradle` file. For use outside of Gradle, you will need to amend your scripts to point to your `zipalign` copy of choice.

Answer (score 1):

To use it with gradle simply configure the release build type like this.

```
buildTypes {

     release {
        zipAlign true
        ...
    }
}
```